# SQL DATEDIFF for clock positions

Tags: sql, ms-access, datediff

I need to calculate the number of clock positions (Hours) between times.

Database has columns (Clock_At_From, Clock_To)

with values like:

```
10, 2
6, 9
```

I used this sql query to get the number of hours between times.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("h", "2005-05-05" + str(c.Clock_At_From) + ":00:00", "2005-05-05" + str(c.Clock_To) + ":00:00")   
FROM [Conditions] as c
```

The "2005-05-05" and ":00:00" is just a placeholder, I only care about the hours.

This sorta works. However when the number is:

```
10, 2
```

returns -8

I need something that does if number is negative add 12 to the value. How can I do this?

Using MS-Access

Comment: No need for DateDiff, just use an IIf to check whether or not the first number is larger than the second, then add 12. Also, if the input is 1 and 2, how do you know if that's 1 AM to 2 AM or 1 AM to 2 PM or vice versa?

Comment: @Rabbit Its more a angle thing then time. Like when a pilot says bogey at 2 o'clock they are referring to a position versus the actual time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query like this. This example is written for 24 hours.

```
SELECT IIF(clock_to - clock_at_from < 0, 
           24 - (clock_at_from - clock_to),
           clock_to - clock_at_from) AS diff
FROM Conditions
```